# Aligning a navigation button to the right with bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this html with bootstrap 5. I want to move the nextbutton navigation link to the extreme right
of the page. Currently it is shifted to the left.

what is wrong here? what can I change to move it to the right?

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-lg-9 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3">
                <h1 class="mt-5">Sounds good! Let's move on and review your info.</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                    <div id="next-parent" class="resize-animated-image">
                        <div id="nextbutton" @onclick="NextClickHandler" class="icon round-button arrow"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2 col-lg-9 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3">
      <h1 class="mt-5">Sounds good! Let's move on and review your info.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div id="next-parent" class="resize-animated-image">
     <div id="nextbutton" @onclick="NextClickHandler" class="icon round-button arrow">button</div>
      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will do. I do you are missing a closing main div

Comment: It looks good but the arrow and the text are on the same line. I need the arrow/navigation to be further down the page.  I tried mt-5 and no luck

Comment: can i see the output?

Comment: Sure. I just added it to the question above

Comment: try to remove the mt-5 class in h1 tag

Comment: I did that. It is still the same thing. It is on the same line. I need that arrow to be way down the page.

Comment: It looks better. Is there a way to push everything to the center of the page?

Comment: what do you mean? your question before is how to put the navigation link to the extreme right and now you want to push everything to the center?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I just thought I ask you that. You answered my question

Comment: you can change justify-content-end to justify-content-center if you want to place the button in the center too

Comment: No I don't want to place the button in the center. I want the entire content on the page to be at the center of the page. The arrow button should still stay to the right.

Comment: just add justify-content-center class in the row then all the content that is inside that row will be placed at the center, I think so. you must read the documentation of bootstrap. just vote for the answer if its useful. bye,

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try "ml-auto" in your code!

Comment: Can you be specific where to put the ml-auto?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Add parent element of your button